# Ubuntu 18.04 No Wi-Fi Adapter Found

Tags: wireless, broadcom

There is even no wifi drop-down bar. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16a3] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Limited NetXtreme BCM57786 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4]
03:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Limited BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Limited BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:96bc]
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
--
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00ef]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of the following command in Terminal: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`.